# loader for ng-repeat in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have repeated data in a table like

```
<td>{{todo.title}}</td>
<td>
  <button ng-show="loader">Deleting...</button>
  <button ng-hide="loader" ng-click="delete(todo.id)">Delete</button>
</td>
```

Js code:

```
$scope.loader = false;

$scope.delete = function(id) {
  $scope.loader = true;
  $http.delete(url).success(function() {
    $scope.loader = false;
  })
}
```

It's working for deleting record but deleting... Button shows for every row. I can't handle for current row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `loader` as `todo` property

like this

```
<button ng-show="todo.loader">Deleting...</button>
<button ng-hide="todo.loader" ng-click="delete(todo)">Delete</button>
```

JS

```
$scope.delete=function(todo){
   todo.loader=true;
   $http.delete(url).success(function(){
        todo.loader=false;
    })
}
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/yh9zxxzs/1/)**</kbd>